# Express req.files always return blank [object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

I'm trying to save uploaded file *in its original name* (using express-fileupload), when I upload the file it will always be saved in the directory as `[object Object]`.

**Node:**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files)
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  //define file name
  let audiofile = req.files.audiofile;
  //save the file
  audiofile.mv(__dirname + '/' + audiofile + '.mp3', function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('Audio uploaded!');
  });
});
```

**HTML form:**

```
<form ref='uploadForm'
      id='uploadForm'
      action='http://localhost:8080/upload'
      method='post'
      encType="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <button class="btn whitebg main">Choose audio</button>
        <input class="nb" type="file" name="audiofile" />
      </div>
        <input class="nobtn main white" type='submit' value='Upload!' />
      </form>
```

Previously I use `audiofile.mv(__dirname + '/audiofile.mp3'` but obviously it would save every single file as `audiofile.mp3` but I don't want to change the file name. Btw tried using `req.files.audiofile.name` method but I got `name is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let audiofile = req.files.audiofile;
```

`audiofile` is a JSON Object or Array that is why file is saving as  `[object Object]` You need to check using `console.log` or debugging  what is coming inside `audiofile` and get filename from `audiofile` 
check this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON